# How can i install .net 3.5 without internet on xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp, .net-framework

So i have an old windows xp pc im trying to install ***OEM brander*** it needs .net 3.5 and it says re-establishing connection with server ***1 out of 5***, ***2 out of 5*** *exc.* *[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Xru.png)* How do i install it?

Comment: Try here:   https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=25150

Comment: You need to download an offline installer, and copy it in. .Net frameworks are backwards compatible, so you could use latest if you can't find a 3.5 offline installer.

Comment: I posted the Microsoft offline installer and that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download an offline installer, and copy it in.

.Net framework versions are backwards compatible, so you could use the latest if you can't find a 3.5 offline installer. **Note**: .Net Framework versions higher than v4 are **not** supported by the Windows XP OS, though.

John has provided you with a link to the offline installer for v3.5 SP1 at https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=25150